# Jenkins - Timed out connecting to Chrome

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Odd one here that I have not seen before. I decided to load a local instance of Jenkins on my Win 10 Laptop. The service is up and running and everything is building fine but when it tries to open chrome, I see the below in the log. I can execute it from Visual Studio and Command Line with no issues.

Research has mentioned lowering the chromedriver version so I tried with no luck. I have only run jenkins in master/agent config so maybe this has to do with jenkins being run on local host?

```
Starting ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217- 
refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442}) on port 7797
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to 
prevent access by malicious code.
[1571096148.894][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
```

Additional things I have tried....
Creating a new user with all permissions to the jenkins dir
Running the service as the new user

Answer (score 0):

OK I gave up running as a service. I copied the Jenkins.war file to the the directory I wanted. In this case, D:\Jenkins and then I executed:

```
D:\Jenkins>Java -jar Jenkins.war
```

This reloaded the Jenkins install. I added msbuild/tfs plugins and I am now running jenkins from the command line vs as a service. Everything is working now.

Just a work around but it may help someone else out.